# Incompatibility between C++ Google Test, Qt and boost libraries on a VERY simple case (core dumped)

Tags: c++, qt, boost, googletest

I am starting a C++ project in which I wish to use elements from both the Qt environment and boost libraries. Also, Google Test will be the unit testing framework.

It is the very beginning of the project and therefore it contains a tiny amount of code (a few member accessor functions for one class).

Yet, as soon as I started to compile with boost (boost_filesystem), I got a core dumped in the middle of the tests run by Google Test. These tests were running fine before. The core dump occurs long before I am calling any boost function. Also, even if I comment out the code that call boost functions and just link with boost, I still get the core dump in the same place.

This core dump occurs in the middle of a list of EXPECT_DEATH calls that I use to test that my Q_ASSERT assertions do indeed get triggered on invalid inputs. I know that EXPECT_DEATH is costly but so far it worked fine (before I linked to Boost). In my current test scenario, I must be calling it a little under 100 times. Here is an example:

```
l_item.setFlags(CorpusStore::FULL_EDGE);
EXPECT_DEATH(l_item.text(), "");
EXPECT_DEATH(l_item.setText("toto"), "");
```

The code that will trigger the death is:

```
void CorpusStore::Item::setText(const QString& p_text){
    qCDebug(g_cat_store) << QString("setting text to [%1] (len = %2)").arg(p_text).arg(p_text.length());
    Q_ASSERT_X((m_flags & (ITEM_IS_VERTEX | ITEM_IS_SIMPLE)) != 0, "Item::setText()", "cannot be a full edge");
    Q_ASSERT_X(((m_flags & (ITEM_IS_VERTEX | ITEM_IS_SIMPLE)) == ITEM_IS_SIMPLE) ? (p_text.length() < SIMPLE_EDGE_TEXT_LEN) : true,
           "Item::setText()", "simple edge --> length must be <     SIMPLE_EDGE_TEXT_LEN");
    Q_ASSERT_X(((m_flags & (ITEM_IS_VERTEX | ITEM_IS_SIMPLE)) == (ITEM_IS_VERTEX | ITEM_IS_SIMPLE)) ?
               (p_text.length() < SIMPLE_VERTEX_TEXT_LEN) : true,
           "Item::setText()", "simple vertex --> length must be < SIMPLE_VERTEX_TEXT_LEN");
```

Like I said, I have a little under 100 tests that look like this (plus a number of `EXPECT_EQ`, etc)

I know that people are going to tell me that I should not use so many `EXPECT_DEATH` to test asserts and that I should use Google Test's own assert macros instead of Qt's. Okay, Okay, but ...

1. This is what I want to do ...
2. The core dump should not happen even if I use a million `EXPECT_DEATH`.
   There is obviously a bug somewhere and so it is worth investigating (hint, hint, Boost, Qt and Google Test people)

Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    CorpusStore::CorpusEnv::init();
    //CorpusStore::Storage::init();

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The commented out line in the middle is where the Boost functions would be called. As I said, I get a core dumped nonetheless. `CorpusStore::CorpusEnv::init()` is my own initialization code that I need to call before the tests begin.

I am using the Qt build system, which may not be familiar to many. In essence it generates a Makefile, just like CMake does. In addition to the Qt libraries, I am just linking with two more: `libgtest.a` and `libboost_filesystem.a`

HELP!!....

------------ EDITS ------------
Based on @Some programmer dude comments below.

On the debugger, I am just seeing that the core dump happens in the middle of a malloc call and I can see some disassembled code. But the context (what call caused it) is not clear. Some of the code just before the malloc call contains what appears to be Qt Symbols. The function call stack starts inside the libc-start.c library which, I guess, must be called after a fork call due to the `EXPECT_DEATH`. What is weird is that this stretch of code worked ok before I started linking with libboost_filesystem.a and no code from that library does appear in the debugger function call stack. If I remove all the boost related code and stop linking to it, my whole test suit works.

This is the situation where it happens (messages from qDebug()):

```
...
[Debug] 17:14:32.209 (void CorpusStore::Item::setFlags(CorpusStore::FlagField) ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:338) "Setting flags to 0x3 (0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011)"
[Debug] 17:14:32.209 (void CorpusStore::Item::setReciprocal(CorpusStore::ItemID) ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:498) "setting reciprocal edge to 2416"
[Fatal] 17:14:32.209 ( ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:499) ASSERT failure in Item::setReciprocal(): "accessing the reciprocal of an item that is not a full edge", file ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp, line 499
[Debug] 17:14:32.309 (CorpusStore::ItemID CorpusStore::Item::reciprocal() ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:506) "Getting reciprocal edge ..."
[Fatal] 17:14:32.309 ( ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:507) ASSERT failure in Item::reciprocal(): "accessing the reciprocal of an item that is not a full edge", file ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp, line 507
[Debug] 17:14:32.408 (void CorpusStore::Item::setFlags(CorpusStore::FlagField) ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:338) "Setting flags to 0x2 (0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010)"
[Debug] 17:14:32.408 (void CorpusStore::Item::setReciprocal(CorpusStore::ItemID) ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:498) "setting reciprocal edge to 2417"
[Fatal] 17:14:32.408 ( ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:499) ASSERT failure in Item::setReciprocal(): "accessing the reciprocal of an item that is not a full edge", file ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp, line 499
[Debug] 17:14:32.507 (CorpusStore::ItemID CorpusStore::Item::reciprocal() ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:506) "Getting reciprocal edge ..."
[Fatal] 17:14:32.507 ( ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:507) ASSERT failure in Item::reciprocal(): "accessing the reciprocal of an item that is not a full edge", file ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp, line 507
[Debug] 17:14:32.606 (void CorpusStore::Item::setFlags(CorpusStore::FlagField) ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:338) "Setting flags to 0x2 (0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010)"
[Debug] 17:14:32.607 (void CorpusStore::Item::setFirstEdge(CorpusStore::ItemID) ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:518) "setting first edge to 2327"
[Fatal] 17:14:32.607 ( ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp:519) ASSERT failure in Item::setFirstEdge(): "accessing the first edge on a non-full item", file ../Corpus/corpus_store.cpp, line 519
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Each of the `[Fatal]` messages above corresponds to an `EXPECT_DEATH` test that has *succeeded* because a `Q_ASSERT` has been triggered (see code above). Normally, this output would continue for about 50 more lines, corresponding to more tests. Now it is interrupted in the middle. The point at which it stops doe not seem special in any way. But it stops always at the same point. It is not random.

When the crash happens, I do not see any of my variables (or my function calls) in the debugger, which is why I think it must take place during a fork call before my code gets activated. A problem related to the loading of a library could happen at that point I guess?

This is what I see in the debugger window:
[image: Debugger]
None of it seems particularly helpful.

Comment: Exactly *where* does the crash happen? If you catch it in a debugger, where in your code does it happen? If it's from an assert, which one is it? At the location of the crash, what are the values of the involved variables? Are they what you expect them to be (well, obviously not since you crashed, but humor us)? What *are* the values, and what did you expect them to be?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: On the debugger, I am just seeing that it happens in the middle of a malloc call and I can see some disassembled code. But the context (what call caused it) is not shown. I think it is because it happens in the middle of an EXPECT_DEATH, during which the process is probably forking. That may be the reason the context is lost, I think

Comment: Where did you get your `libboost_filesystem.a` from?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and a full backtrace.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Update: On the debugger, I can see that some of the code just before the malloc call contains what appears to be Qt Symbols. The function call stack starts inside the libc-start.c library which, I guess, must be called after a fork call. What is weird is that this stretch of code worked ok before I started linking with libboost_filesystem.a and yet no code from that library does appear in the debugger function call stack. If I remove all the boost related code and stop linking to it, my whole test suite works.

Comment: @fi11222 Please [edit] your question to include this information. It should be part of the main question not as comments.

Comment: I smell an ABI/ODR issue. Are all libraries compiled with the same version/flags of the compiler? Do all included headers exactly match the linked libraries?

Comment: @Genjutsu and @sehe : The `libboost_filesystem.a` comes from the Ubuntu (Debian) Boost package. It has not been recompiled locally. Could that be the reason? ABI is "Application binary interface", right? What is ODR?

Comment: ODR is the "one definition rule". In this case it would mean that it is the linker that is misbehaving due to names in the `libboost.a` file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

Thanks to @sehe and @Genjutsu's comments above.

I recompiled `libboost_filesystem.a` from sources and it works now.

So the takeaway is: Don't trust Ubuntu/Debian's binary packages. For Boost, at least, they are not guaranteed to work. Why? I have no idea ...